# ¿Cómo convertir cada línea de un archivo de texto en una lista utilizando python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que leo un archivo de texto pero quiero que cada línea contenida en el archivo se convierta en una lista. ¿Alguién tiene una idea de cómo hacerlo?

Para la apertura del archivo utilizo:

```
archivo = open('Ejemplo.txt','r')
```

La salida que busco es que cada linea del archivo se convierta en una lista
por ejemplo:

```
['una','vez','en','la','escuela','llegue']
['cuando','estaba','lloviendo']
['me','enferme','durante','dos','semanas']
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Jaruc, deberias aportar el código para ver como lees el archivo y poder ayudarte en base a el. Con que cada linea sea una lista ¿a que te refieres, a una lista con las palabras de la linea? . Si fuera eso basta con usar `lista = linea.split()`. Deberias completar tu pregunta con el código y con un ejemplo de txt y su salida esperada. Mirate [mcve]. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta como te dije en el comentario con usar el método [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), que hace precisamente eso, retornar una lista a partir de una cadena separada usando un separador determinado (en este caso un espacio):

**archivo.txt:**

> una vez en la escuela llegue
>   cuando estaba lloviendo
>   me enferme durante dos semanas

**Código:**

```
salida = []
with open('archivo.txt', 'r') as f:
    lineas = [linea.split() for linea in f]

for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)
```

**Salida:**

> ['una', 'vez', 'en', 'la', 'escuela', 'llegue']
>   ['cuando', 'estaba', 'lloviendo']
>   ['me', 'enferme', 'durante', 'dos', 'semanas']